# jQuery have to wait for php

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm devloping a tool with MySQL, HTML5, jQuery and Json. On my website I have 3 tables, but one of them has to be transposed. So I write this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#druckerdetails').dataTable({
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bSort": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": false,
    "sAjaxSource": 'php/index_druckerdetails.php?druckername=RAGPLM002'
  });
  $(function () {
    var table = $('#druckerdetails');
    alert('Besten Dank, dass Sie isyPrint benutzen :)');
    table.find('thead tr').detach().prependTo(table.find('tbody'));
    var t = table.find('tbody').eq(0);
    var r = t.find('tr');
    var cols = r.length;
    var rows = r.eq(0).find('td,th').length;
    var cell, next, tem, i = 0;
    var tb = $('<tbody></tbody>');
    while (i < rows) {
      cell = 0;
      tem = $('<tr></tr>');
      while (cell < cols) {
        next = r.eq(cell++).find('td,th').eq(0);
        tem.append(next);
      }
      tb.append(tem);
      ++i;
    }
    table.find('tbody').remove();
    $(tb).appendTo(table);
    $(table)
      .find('tbody tr:eq(0)')
      .detach()
      .appendTo(table.find('thead'))
      .children();
    table.show();
  });
});
```

With this alert all is fine and works, because the php-file has enough time to return the Json-String. But if there is no alert, the JavaScript doesn't wait for the data of the php whith the MySQL-query. So the data is missing in on the website.

Without alert:
http://www.computerbase.de/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=359923&d=1377067918

So here is the timeline (isyprint_home.js & index_druckerdetails.php):
http://www.computerbase.de/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=359927&d=1377072271

So what I have to do, that the js-file waits until the json-string was returned?

Thanks and sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1):

You can use deferred render:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "sources/arrays.txt",
        "bDeferRender": true
    } );
} );
```

[Font](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/defer_render.html)

if the datatable can't treat you problem, i recomend you to get the json feed from separated ajax call, and when its finish you put it in the datatable. Like this:

```
var feed;
 $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url:  'www.test.com/mydatatablefeed',
   success: function(data){
      feed = data;    
   }
   });

 $('#example').dataTable( {
        "aaData": feed
    } );   
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ajaxComplete or data table callback which should be called when data is actually returned.
You can also add callback to event when loading data has failed, so you can notify user about failure.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax source is used to load the data asynchronously, so this behavior is expected.  You need to link your "transposition" code to a notification that data was loaded, or modify it as it's being loaded.  Personally, I would fix this "problem" in the PHP returning the JSON, so it gives the table data in a format it understands.

But if you want to go with this, the callbacks have a function where you can override the data fetching: http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks

> **fnServerData** This parameter allows you to override the default function which obtains the data from the server ($.getJSON) so something more suitable for your application. For example you could use POST data, or pull information from a Gears or AIR database.

Here's an example showing how to do additional processing w/the data: http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html